# give a sequence for 2 functions in javascript

Tags: javascript

i have 2 functions which should be initiated 1 by 1 sequentially.

```
    mounted() {
  this.A();
  this.B();
},

function async A() {
 let res = $api.function();

 this.temp = res.data.temp
}

function async B() {
 if(this.temp) {
  ...
 }
}
```

after A function finished, B function should be started because of 'temp'

how can i do this?

I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    await A();
    await B();
    resolve();
});
```

is there any way to use 'async/await' to do this? like this?

```
     function async init() {
      let result = await A();
      if (result) {
      B();
      }
     }
```

Comment: if `$api.function()` is asynchronous AND returns a Promise .. use `let res = await $api.function();` in function A - the fact that you have two `async` functions and no `await` INSIDE those functions suggests you don't understand async/await and promises ... also `new Promise(async (resolve, reject)` is virtually never what you want to do

Comment: btw, the correct synatx is `async function init`, not `function async init`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mounted() {
  this.A();
  this.B();
},

function async A() {
  let res = await $api.function(); // <-----------------------

  this.temp = res.data.temp
}

function B() {
  ...
}
```